# How can I get intellisense to work in Visual Studio code with node.js?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I am using VS Code for my node.js project but I have no intellisense on my modules. *Go to definition* or *Find all references* do not work either.
How can I get intellisense and all these features like *Go to definition* etc. to work in VS code in a node.js project?

Comment: Using VSC too, intellisense works as expected. Try to add the jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json. If you are using javascript, try updating to the latest release.

Comment: I mean getting it to work across node modules, not only for local files. For example if I require a module in my javascript file to have intellisense on the methods and properties of this module.

Answer (score 0):

You may have disabled the default IntelliSense in VS Code.
To enable it you need to look in extensions
**@builtin TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUr2x.png)